# Apply some events and actions on <a> tag after window load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some links in my page and when any link has clicked it goes to another page and make window load.

But I want to make some action on the link that has been clicked last and I applied. But when window load happen everything gone.

These links are common to each page.

Please help me. Sorry for any mistakes.

THANKS.

Comment: Sorry, you will have to be more specific.  I guess that English may not be your first language but it doesn't really make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're trying to do something like highlight the current page's link in a navigation menu. Check this out...

http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Auto-Selecting_Navigation

Comment: Yeah, that's good if you already have the variables transferred to the next page. But perhaps that's what he needed :)

Answer (score 1):

**You will either need to send the variables to the next page via GET or POST**

or

**Save them in a cookie, a database or in a file on the server.**

---

Let's say the variables are `show=1` and `page=phones`.

---

You could send the variables like this:

```
var show = 1;
var page = 'phones';
$('#link').click(function(){
  top.location.href = 'page.html?show='+show+'&=page'+phones+'';
});
```

Then you could fetch the variables on the next page with either a serverside language like PHP or ASP, or you can create a smart function in javascript to fetch the part of the URL you need:

```
function getParam(name) {
    return decodeURI(
        (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
    );
}
```

and use it like this (in page.html):

```
var show = getParam('show');
var page = getParam('page');
```

---

If you would like to save the variables to a cookie in the users browser you could use these functions:

```
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
  {
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

And use them like this:

In your first page:

```
var show = 1;
var page = 'phones';
setCookie(''+show+'',show,5); // expire after 5 days
setCookie(''+page+'',page,5); // expire after 5 days
// now redirect to other page like in the first example
$('#link').click(function(){
  top.location.href = 'page.html';
});
```

In your second page:

```
var show = getCookie('show');
var page = getCookie('page');

if (show === 1) {
  // Do whatever you like, because cookie 'show' is 1
}
```

I hope it helps!